# How do I make a button use an existing layout

Tags: android

I am new to android and struggle with the following question for quite some time now. I created a few buttons in a for-loop. Under res\layout I created how I want a button to look like. Is it possible to make the button use that layout as it is easy to modify it in the editor? Currently I am using LayoutParams and am setting everything through calling the respective methods (only setting the text "push me" in the example below).

This is the code in my MainActivity.java file:

```
for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
            Button myButton = new Button (this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            myButton.setText("Push Me");
            LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
            ll.addView(myButton);
        }
```

This is the content of the buttonlayout.xml I want the buttons to be using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttonidd">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also want to change the ID of every button created that way to "i".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this just seems like a bad approach in general, i'd suggest using a recyclerview instead

Comment: As @a_local_nobody has said using a `RecyclerView` would be far better. You can even uses the existing `buttonlayout.xml` as the `ViewHolder` with little to no changes. You can pretty much copy paste this example https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview . If you go with original approach you may experience performance problems with 50 buttons being created all at once and view manipulation to get them inside the `LinearLayout` at the very least the app will not be as snappy on older phones.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will check it out then

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView to easily create a large number of similar components, and it is better for mobile phones. Because of the ViewHolder.

If the number of components you need is not that many, and you want to dynamically adjust the position of your components in your case, please note that your layout uses `ConstraintLayout`, all components that are dynamically adjusted must set constraints.